# Hardware implementation of trigonometric functions?

Tags: performance

Is anybody aware as to whether there are any modern microcontrollers that have hardware implementations of trigonometric functions? According to my understanding, modern CPUs have basic maths functions such as square roots and the trigonometric functions implemented in hardware to increase the speed and/or throughput of these maths functions. Do any widely used microcontrollers you know of have similar hardware implementations?

The reason I am asking this is because I want to know if it is feasible to implement more efficient trigonometric functions for specific use cases. On modern CPUs with the right compiler settings, it is almost always faster to use or derive from the built in trigonometric functions, rather than rolling your own software implementation specific to your problem.

Comment: It does belong in the question doesn't it.. hehe. And no, I'm talking about whether software implementations can realistically be faster than the standard implementations provided by standard libraries. Be that specialised versions of the taylor series, or other non-standard approaches to implementing something like sine.

Comment: I'm actually beating around the bush to avoid embarrassing myself, I have a class to generate a continuous sine wave of a constant frequency/sampling rate, and it doesn't have a place in modern high performance code due to the aforementioned built in trigonometric functions present on modern CPUs. However I would like to know if it has a use in lower processing power devices such as microcontrollers and microprocessors. Should I delete this question and actually provide the code for criticism?

Comment: "are you not aware of the purpose of this site?" mate all I was asking was if microcontrollers had something like a single machine instruction to compute trigonometric functions. There doesn't seem to be a general "microcontroller" stack exchange site so I thought this place would be best. Apparently not.

Comment: [Electronics Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) is more targeted at microcontrollers in general. For your question to be on-topic here you would need to be asking about an Arduino implementation. As Arduino is, generally speaking, targeted at beginners there would probably be no such thing.

Comment: For small / slow MCUs it is more common to use a LUT than to calculate these kind of numbers on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the answer to your main question, but I will try to answer
the underlying question:

> I want to know if it is feasible to implement more efficient
> trigonometric functions for specific use cases.

There are microcontrollers that do *not* have hardware implementations
of trig functions, and that is the main point. The AVRs powering many
Arduinos are among them: they don't even have hardware floating point.
The libc provides implementations of the trig functions that are both
quite accurate (about 24 bits of accuracy) and very slow (about
100 µs for a `cos()` on an Uno).

There are also situations where you do not need that level of accuracy.
So yes, custom trig functions that hit the right balance between speed
and accuracy can be helpful on Arduinos. Note that the right balance is
project specific, so there is no one-size-fits-all, and rolling your own
can make sense.

For reference, I once wrote a fixed-point `cos()` accurate to
9.53 × 10<sup>−5</sup> that ran in 6.77 µs on average on
an Uno. I can provide a link if someone is interested. If you can do
better (faster at same accuracy, or more accurate at same speed) I
definitely would love to see that.

Comment: I wrote a class that generated a continuous sine wave using the spring equation (F = -kx, where x is the desired resting length of the spring), basically meaning that each sample of the sine wave (assuming a constant sampling rate and frequency) would only require two multiplications and two additions. The tradeoff for this solution is that it is *continuous*, you cannot call sin(1), then sin(5), then sin(3), you just sample from a sine wave of a set frequency. There are two other tradeoffs, memory for storage of the spring state, and the integration of floating point errors.

Comment: The integration of floating point errors does not have a large effect on the shape of the wave, it just means it tends to go in and out of sync with the sin function after multiple samplings. You can recalibrate the function by calling standard sine and cosine function once per recalibration. I don't not why I'm talking about this. I just wanted to talk about it. Because I'm very egotistical.

Comment: I wanted to test if this solution actually is faster than repeatedly calling something like sin(x) repeatedly to fill a buffer or something, but I appear to have misplaced the cable I need to actually program my Arduino.